# Images do not show in the website, but they appear on new tab

Tags: images

I am new to wordpress. I updated my wordpress website to the current version since I did not take care of it since 2013.

However, after I updated it, my images do not appear on my website anymore. The pages only shows white blank space where the images should be. I can open the images on new tabs without any problem.

I suspect that the problem lays on the theme setting, because when I changed to the other theme, it worked.

I want to keep my current theme for my website. Where can I check the code to get the images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to learn about the [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/), which is the process that is used to select the code that 'builds' the page. Within the template is the code that will display images, content, etc.

You will also want to learn about "[Child Themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)", which is a way of customizing a theme without affecting the theme code. You don't want to modify the theme's code because any changes you make will be overwritten by a theme update.

You might also consider contacting the theme's support forum to ask questions there about your theme. You have already determined the theme is at fault, so the theme's support is the place to ask questions about theme problems.

So, the template is what needs to be changed. And to do this properly, create a Child Theme and copy your theme's template in there, and modify that code.

Comment: Interesting. A 'downvote' for an answer that matches the question with links to information that will help the OP understand how templates work. And why Child themes are good. And to mention that theme support is better done on the theme's support page, rather than here. Oh well.  IMHO, downvotes should include a comment so the person answering can improve their next answer, or add to the answer.